# What is the meaning of 'not very far off barter'?

Tags: meaning

> In the process, it is accelerating the spread of banking in an economy that, according to Michel Losembe, the bow-tied president of the Congolese Banking Association, is "**not very far off barter**".

What is the meaning of 'not very far off barter'?

Comment: Your dictionary will define both [**far off**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/far-off?s=t) and [**barter.**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/barter?&o=100074&s=t) Did you consult a dictionary to learn about these words in English? A dictionary should always be the first source you consult when you encounter a word or expression you don't understand. In the best outcome, you can figure things out for yourself!

Comment: I know the meaning of far off and barter...But I still not sure the meaning of this phrase.So I have to ask here for help..@P.E.Dant

Comment: Because the translation of this short phrase in my language is wrong..So I ask  it here..@P.E.Dant

Comment: Whatever you do, do **not** rely on translating into your own language. Translators are frequently wrong. There is no "short cut." If you want to learn English, you have to learn _in_ English. When you understand how important a good _English_ dictionary is, your skills will improve. A link to a "dictionary of dictionaries" is [**here.**](http://www.onelook.com) This will make it easier to consult multiple dictionaries; sometimes this will help when you encounter a very difficult or confusing word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barter is the system of exchanging goods for other goods without using money. 'Not very far off barter' here means not too different from barter (or not much more advanced than barter).